# How to align columns in multiple stacked tables?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get two tables, with one on top of the other, to align their columns.

The second table has an extra column, but the rest of the columns are the same as the first. And I'm trying to get the columns they have in common aligned.

I tried `empty-cells: show;` but that didn't work.
If you were to run the below on an editor, basically the I would like "New Column" to be skipped in the 1st table, and "Column 1" and the rest to be aligned in a single column.

```css
html {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 6% 6%;
}

h1 {
  color: #003366;
  font-size: 20x;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #696969;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1.8% 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: justify;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  empty-cells: show;
}

.second-table td:not(:first-child):nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

th {
  color: #0000CC;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

tr td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
}

tr td span {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.first-table .first-row {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.underweight {
  color: #0000FF;
}

.overweight {
  color: green;
}

.box {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <table class="first-table">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="first-row">
      <td>Label 1</td>
      <td>13%</td>
      <td>25%</td>
      <td>36%</td>
      <td>48%</td>
      <td>57%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label 2</td>
      <td>7%</td>
      <td>15%</td>
      <td>24%</td>
      <td>32%</td>
      <td>38%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label 3</td>
      <td>68%</td>
      <td>51%</td>
      <td>35%</td>
      <td>18%</td>
      <td>5%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label 4</td>
      <td>12%</td>
      <td>9%</td>
      <td>5%</td>
      <td>2%</td>
      <td>0%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label 5</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>Text</h2>

  <table class="second-table">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>New Column</th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Communication Services</td>
      <td>10%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">9%</span></td>
      <td>10%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">11%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">12%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Consumer Discretionary</td>
      <td>10%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">5%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">6%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">9%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Consumer Staples</td>
      <td>7%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">15%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">13%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">11%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">9%</span></td>
      <td>7%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Energy</td>
      <td>5%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">9%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">6%</span></td>
      <td>5%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Financials</td>
      <td>13%</td>
      <td>13%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">15%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">16%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">17%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">18%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>REITs</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">5%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Health Care</td>
      <td>15%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">16%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">17%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">17%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">18%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">20%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Industrials</td>
      <td>9%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">10%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">5%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">4%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Materials</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">5%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">2%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">0%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Technology</td>
      <td>21%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">9%</span<</td>
          <td><span class="underweight">12%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">16%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">18%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">20%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Utilities</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">2%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">2%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">0%</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use two tables for any reason? If not, one table could work like this:

```css
html {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 6% 6%;
}

h1 {
  color: #003366;
  font-size: 20x;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #696969;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1.8% 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: justify;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  empty-cells: show;
}

.second-table td:not(:first-child):nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

th {
  color: #0000CC;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

tr td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
}

tr td span {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.first-table .first-row {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.underweight {
  color: #0000FF;
}

.overweight {
  color: green;
}

.box {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="first-table">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="first-row">
      <td>Label 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>13%</td>
      <td>25%</td>
      <td>36%</td>
      <td>48%</td>
      <td>57%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Label 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>7%</td>
      <td>15%</td>
      <td>24%</td>
      <td>32%</td>
      <td>38%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Label 3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>68%</td>
      <td>51%</td>
      <td>35%</td>
      <td>18%</td>
      <td>5%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Label 4</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12%</td>
      <td>9%</td>
      <td>5%</td>
      <td>2%</td>
      <td>0%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Label 5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
    </tr>

 <tr style = "border: 0; height: auto;"><td colspan ="7">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
 </td></tr>
 
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>New Col</th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Communication Services</td>
      <td>10%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">9%</span></td>
      <td>10%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">11%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">12%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Consumer Discretionary</td>
      <td>10%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">5%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">6%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">9%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Consumer Staples</td>
      <td>7%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">15%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">13%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">11%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">9%</span></td>
      <td>7%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Energy</td>
      <td>5%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">9%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">6%</span></td>
      <td>5%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Financials</td>
      <td>13%</td>
      <td>13%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">15%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">16%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">17%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">18%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>REITs</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">5%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Health Care</td>
      <td>15%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">16%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">17%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">17%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">18%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">20%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Industrials</td>
      <td>9%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">10%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">5%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">4%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Materials</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">5%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">2%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">0%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Technology</td>
      <td>21%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">9%</span<</td>
          <td><span class="underweight">12%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">16%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">18%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">20%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Utilities</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">2%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">2%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">0%</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you -- and yes there are going to be text between the two tables, which is why they're separated.

Comment: I modified it to add text in that middle empty table cell.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this:

```
.first-table tr td:first-child {
  width: 46%;
}
```

I can't think of any other way to do this easily in CSS besides hardcoding the width of the first table's first column. With JS the tables could reference each others current cell sizes but with pure CSS I don't think copying the current dynamically determined style/size like that from one element to another is possible.

```css
html {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 6% 6%;
}

h1 {
  color: #003366;
  font-size: 20x;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #696969;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 1.8% 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: justify;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  empty-cells: show;
}

.second-table td:not(:first-child):nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

th {
  color: #0000CC;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

tr td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
}

tr td span {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.first-table .first-row {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.underweight {
  color: #0000FF;
}

.overweight {
  color: green;
}

.box {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.first-table tr td:first-child {
  width: 46%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <table class="first-table">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="first-row">
      <td>Label 1</td>
      <td>13%</td>
      <td>25%</td>
      <td>36%</td>
      <td>48%</td>
      <td>57%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label 2</td>
      <td>7%</td>
      <td>15%</td>
      <td>24%</td>
      <td>32%</td>
      <td>38%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label 3</td>
      <td>68%</td>
      <td>51%</td>
      <td>35%</td>
      <td>18%</td>
      <td>5%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label 4</td>
      <td>12%</td>
      <td>9%</td>
      <td>5%</td>
      <td>2%</td>
      <td>0%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Label 5</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>Text</h2>

  <table class="second-table">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>New Column</th>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Communication Services</td>
      <td>10%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">9%</span></td>
      <td>10%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">11%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">12%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Consumer Discretionary</td>
      <td>10%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">5%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">6%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">9%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Consumer Staples</td>
      <td>7%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">15%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">13%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">11%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">9%</span></td>
      <td>7%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Energy</td>
      <td>5%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">9%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">6%</span></td>
      <td>5%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Financials</td>
      <td>13%</td>
      <td>13%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">15%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">16%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">17%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">18%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>REITs</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">5%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Health Care</td>
      <td>15%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">16%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">17%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">17%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">18%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">20%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Industrials</td>
      <td>9%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">10%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">8%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">5%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">4%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Materials</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">5%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">2%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">0%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Technology</td>
      <td>21%</td>
      <td><span class="underweight">9%</span<</td>
          <td><span class="underweight">12%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">16%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">18%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">20%</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="box">&#9632;</span>Utilities</td>
      <td>3%</td>
      <td><span class="overweight">7%</span></td>
      <td><span class="overweight">4%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">2%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">2%</span></td>
      <td><span class="underweight">0%</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```